# Selenium Web Driver in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: c#, azure, selenium-chromedriver, azure-service-fabric

**Background Information:**
I have currently built a screen scraper using Chromedriver to screen scrape a website and this is just a console application. I now want to move this application to use Azure Service Fabric since it has a lot of benefits in terms of scalability.

**Problem:**
I have converted the screen scraper to use Azure Service Fabric Stateless Service and it runs in my local development environment. The only issue is that I can't see the screen scraper run interactively anymore since it does not open a chrome browser and navigate to the different pages. I know the screen scraper still runs since it returns the screen scraped data I expect. Initially I thought it was the user that the service runs as since it runs using the 'NETWORK SERVICE' account. I changed it to run under a domain user of myself using the following code:

```
<Principals>
  <Users>
    <User Name="SfUser" AccountName="Domain\UserName" AccountType="DomainUser" Password="pass" />
  </Users>
</Principals>
<Policies>
  <DefaultRunAsPolicy UserRef="SfUser" />
</Policies>
```

It still does not run interactively. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not a service fabric issue. If you start selenium driver from a non-interactive mode then you dont see the browser. May be change service to trigger command line then run selenium?